# Moq repository with attached Linq expression.

Tags: c#, linq, moq

I'm trying to Mock my Repository and I have a function that calls it that looks like this:

```
return _mailingListRepository.Find(ml => ml.EmailAddress == email).Any();
```

I setup my Mock Repository like this:

```
_mailingListRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<MailingList, bool>>>())).Returns((IEnumerable<MailingList>) null);
```

But it then throws an exception: Value cannot be null. What should I return in my setup?

Comment: Can you post the method you are testing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want your mock to return an empty list?  If so, then return `Enumerable.Empty<MailingList>()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
_mailingListRepositoryMock.Setup(m => m.Find(It.IsAny<Expression<Func<MailingList, bool>>>())).Returns<IEnumerable<MailingList>>(null);
```